# SQL Server 2019 BDC deployment on AKS stuck at Check controller logs for more details

Tags: azure-aks, sql-server-2019

I setup a 3 node kubernetes cluster on AKS for the purpose of deploying SQL Server 2019 BDC.

The installation went smooth for sometime and got stuck at *"Cluster 'mssql-cluster' is not ready after 15.0 minutes. Check controller logs for more details"*.

This is the complete output:

```
Starting cluster deployment.
Waiting for cluster controller to start.
Waiting for cluster controller to start.
Waiting for cluster controller to start.
Waiting for cluster controller to start.
Waiting for cluster controller to start.
Cluster controller endpoint is available at XX.6X.2X.1XY:3X0X0.
Cluster control plane is ready.
Compute pool is ready.
Master pool is ready.
Data pool is ready.
Storage pool is ready.
Cluster 'mssql-cluster' is not ready after 15.0 minutes. Check controller logs for more details.
```

I'm new to both AKS and BDC so I don't know where to locate the controller logs. Can someone point me in the right direction. The deployment uses the AKS-Dev-Test profile without any change.

At this point, how can I access the available controller endpoint and what will it give me at this juncture?

Update:-

I ran azdata bdc status show and the error seems to be in HDFS/Spark.

```
hdfs           waiting  unhealthy       StatefulSet sparkhead is not ready with 0 ready pods and 1 unready pods
spark          waiting  unhealthy       StatefulSet sparkhead is not ready with 0 ready pods and 1 unready pods
```

Thanks,
rgn

Comment: Can you check logs of sparkhead statefulset to see why that is not ready More information can be checked using 
`kubectl describe statefulset sparkhead` (This assumes it is running in default namespace)

Comment: I dont know where the logs are. Where & how can I locate them?
<<Can you check logs of sparkhead statefulset>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with resources as I had picked VMs with limited resources which is not appropriate for BDC.

Thanks,
rgn

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  12s (x107 over 154m)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) exceed max volume count.
```

Comment: This got solved after the node was updated to higher resources?

Comment: No. My Pay-As-You-Go service did not let me use more than 10 vCPUs.

Comment: You can contact azure support to get quota for higher cpu resources. It should solve the problem then.